# how to run a list of items in a for loop parallel with threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I currently have a list of items, which i want to execute in parallel using threads, I currently use multiprocessing approach with pool.map function to run the list of items in parallel, But i would like to test with basic threading approach in python. My code looks like this

```
     A=['Bounce.mo','Hello.mo','Circle.mo']
     from multiprocessing import Pool
     from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
     pool = ThreadPool()
     pool.map(parallel,A)
```

How to run the threads in parallel to iterate the items in list through for loop?, something like below,

```
     A=['Bounce.mo','Hello.mo','Circle.mo']
     for z in xrange(len(A)):
        # run the threads in parallel
```

Comment: What are you doing with the items? Note that threads will only help if your code is IO-bound.

Comment: i will use an API function which simulates these items and produce a mat file